# Как запихнуть переменную в ответ vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Код

```
def send_some_msg(id, some_text):
    vk_session.method("messages.send", {"user_id":id, "message":some_text,"random_id":0, "money":2, "id_bot":1})

money = 2
id_bot = 1
print(money)
print(id_bot)
id_bot = id_bot + id_bot
print(id_bot)

for event in longpool.listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:
        if event.to_me:
            msg = event.text.lower()
            id = event.user_id
            if msg == "профиль":
                send_some_msg(id, "Профиль: id = id_bot баланс = money")
```

Как сделать чтобы в send_some_msg(id, "Профиль: id = id_bot баланс = money") вместо id_bot и money были цифры переменной?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, что Вам нужно:

```
send_some_msg(id, f"Профиль: id = {id_bot} баланс = {money}")
```